# Window width returns wrong value

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

In IE11 if I/you visit (for viewport testing purposes) http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/ you can see that viewport dimensions across a number of the queries ie window, inner outer etc a wrong, just visit in Chrome and they show correct values.

I was using this script when I noticed and looked further into it:

```
var wi = $(window).width();
$("p.testp").text('Initial screen width: ' + wi + 'px.');
```

My screen is 2048, but is returning 2556 in IE11

Anyone? thanks P

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it, and thanks to Ryan who helped me. Simply zoom was set to 80% in IE 11, and yes Im a Dummy